# Same tables with same data, different SQL Server stored procedure performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have 2 SQL Server 2008 instances installed on the same server. They have same table structures with same data. I have a stored procedure deployed on both of them. The stored procedure performs differently on them. It takes 5 seconds on one instance and 50 seconds on the other to execute the procedure. I think the possible reasons for this are: *index fragmentation, outdated statistics*. I defragmented the indexes and updated the statistics but still no luck. Any ideas on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Add the query plans please. And difference in versions via SELECT @@VERSION?

Comment: Do you have the user and TempDB databases on the same/similar drives? If one is on a slower drive/RAID it's possible to have differences. We still need the execution plans for both situations in order to be able to say anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the two instances indentically configured?

One thing to check is if the instances have the same memory allocation.

Comment: Yes they have the same memory configuration. I use the following query to check the mem configuration. 

SELECT *
FROM   sys.configurations
where description like  '%mem%'

Comment: Are all other configuration settings also identical?

Answer (score 4):

Odds are the statistics are out of date for one of the instances (or both) which is causing crappy execution plans to be generated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `with(recompile)` on the stored procedures to ensure they are both starting from scratch when it comes to the execution plans.